# Eliminar duplicados de un archivo CSV desde Python

Tags: python

Hola tengo un archivo CSV la cual no contiene nombres de columna, quisiera eliminar los duplicados únicamente de la primer columna, pero son datos que no se conocen ejemplo:

```
12343     test1
12343     test2
55555     test4
55555     test1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que el contenido del CSV es exactamente como muestras en la pregunta (es decir, varias líneas y cada línea contiene dos datos, separados entre sí por unos cuantos espacios).

Lo primero es cargar esos datos en Python, para lo cual resulta muy conveniente la biblioteca Pandas. En este caso podemos hacer uso de su función `read_csv()` indicándole como separador la expresión regular `"\s+"` (que significa uno o más espacios, aunque cuenta como espacio también el tabulador), e indicándole que el fichero no tiene nombres de columnas, mediante la opción `header=None`.

Es decir, leemos así los datos:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Fichero.csv", sep=r"\s+", header=None)
```

El resultado, si lo mostramos con `print(df)` es:

```html
       0      1
0  12343  test1
1  12343  test2
2  55555  test4
3  55555  test1
```

Aquí vemos que, aunque en el csv las columnas no tenían nombre, pandas les ha añadido un nombre por defecto, que es el número de columna (0 y 1). También ha añadido un "índice" para numerar las filas, pero no te preocupes por ese número que al final se puede omitir.

Para eliminar duplicados, pandas tiene la función `.drop_duplicates()` que admite como parámetro el nombre de la columna en que nos queremos basar a la hora de detectar esos duplicados. En nuestro caso sería la columna 0, así que:

```
resultado = df.drop_duplicates(0)
```

Al mostrarlo con `print(resultado)` vemos:

```html
       0      1
0  12343  test1
2  55555  test4
```

¡Ha funcionado! Solo queda usar de nuevo pandas para guardar el resultado en un csv, en el formato que quieras. Por ejemplo, si quieres el mismo formato que el fichero de entrada debes usar las siguientes opciones:

```
resultado.to_csv("Resultado.csv", sep="\t", header=None, index=False)
```

En `sep` he puesto un tabulador (pero puedes poner cuatro espacios o lo que prefieras). La opción `header=None` es para que no se vuelquen los nombres de las columnas, y la opción `index=False` para que no se vuelque el índice (o sea, los números de fila).

El resultado en el fichero será:

```html
12343   test1
55555   test4
```